# PoEdit, how to discard translations not being used?

Tags: po, poedit

I need to know how to mark or delete the translations not being use by the project.
Is there a way to do this? I have read about PoEdit, and I can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: update the PO file from your source code. That removes unused strings and adds new strings. See the GNU gettext manual (there's a link in the Help menu) for in-depth explanation of gettext concepts like that.

P.S. The name's "Poedit", not "PoEdit".